# How to fix installation of package marmap with error message?

Tags: r, package, installation

I'm trying to get the library `marmap` and I keep getting this error

```
Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'adehabitatMA':
  method                       from
  print.SpatialPixelsDataFrame sp  
  print.SpatialPixels          sp  
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘marmap’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 namespace ‘vctrs’ 0.2.0 is being loaded, but >= 0.2.1 is required
```

I've tried updating all my packages and I still get this error

these are all the packages I have

```
library(sf)
pacman::p_load(ggplot2, lemon)
library("metR")
library("installr")
library("fortunes")
library(raster)
library("dplyr")
library("remotes")
library("glatos")
library("data.table")
library("tidyr")
library("ggplot2")
library(stringr)

library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library("padr")
library(sp)


library(lubridate)

library(scales)

library(lubridate)
library(lattice)

library(RColorBrewer)
library(viridis)
library("fansi")
library("measurements")
library("sf")
library(R.matlab)
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(marmap)
library("shape")
library(mapdata)
```

I've tried getting rid of the package `raster` and that doesn't work either... still the same error. Can someone tell me how to fix this...

Comment: Have you tried to install or update the vctrs package? And are you using a recent version of R?

Comment: yes to both of those

Comment: Does packageVersion('vctrs') show 0.2.0 or 0.2.1 ?

Comment: still says 0.2.0, but I've tried updating it 3 times

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a `marmap`-related issue since the package builds without any error or warning on all systems tested on CRAN servers: https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_marmap.html. If you are using RSudio, quit the app, launch R and try installing the latest version of `vctrs` from there.

Comment: I tried all that. Turns out I had to uninstall the package ```grDevices``` to update the ```vctrs``` function, and then load that function so I could use ```marmap```